# Google Maps Api v2 - Multiple markers with their own infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to add multiple markers on a map, each one with his own infowindow (I need infowindow to show some informations on multiple lines), but I don't understand how to do that.
I have already read the Google documentation, now I'm looking for a sample code or a tutorial.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code, there are comments that explain my actions. But this will create for you an `InfoWindow` from a predefined XML layout that you will have to create an populate at run time.

next I check if the current clicked marker `InfoWindow` is of a marker that indicates my location, if yes the I present a proper `Toast`, if not I let the user navigate to this location using another Activity:

```
        // Setting a custom info window adapter for the google map
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker args) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                // Getting the position from the marker
                clickMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();

                TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                title.setText(args.getTitle());

                    //Setting InfoWindow click listener
                map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                        if (SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation!=null)
                        {   
                            if (String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) &&
                                    String.valueOf(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude()).substring(0, 8).contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This your current location, navigation is not needed.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FlurryAgent.onEvent("Start navigation window was clicked from daily map");
                                tasksRepository = SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().tasksRepository.getTasksRepository();
                                for (Task tmptask : tasksRepository)
                                {
                                    String tempTaskLat = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude());
                                    String tempTaskLng = String.valueOf(tmptask.getLongtitude());

                                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(tmptask.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8));

                                    if (tempTaskLat.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.latitude).substring(0, 8)) && tempTaskLng.contains(String.valueOf(clickMarkerLatLng.longitude).substring(0, 8)))
                                    {  
                                        task = tmptask;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() ,RoadDirectionsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location could not be found,\nNavigation is not possible.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
                return v;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why would you want to set OnInfoWindowClickListener every time info window pops up? It's enough to do it once at the same time you set InfoWindowAdapter.

Comment: Actually this was not part of the question and can be ignored, but I guess you are right...